# 2 boxes and balls, probability question

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations, statistical-inference

Suppose that we have two identical boxes: box 1 and box 2. Box 1 contains 5 red
balls and 3 blue balls. Box 2 contains 2 red balls and 4 blue balls. A box is selected at random and exactly one ball is drawn from the box. What is the probability that the ball is blue?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's divide this into two cases:

1. Picking box 1 and then a blue ball means the probability of picking box 1 times the probability of picking a blue ball out of box 1, which is 1/2 * 3/8 = 3/16
2. Picking box 2 and then a blue ball means the probability of picking box 2 times the probability of picking a blue ball out of box 2, which is 1/2 * 4/6 = 1/3

We add the two to get the probability is 25/48

Comment: Hey, it’s generally encouraged not to answer [PSQ](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33854/1072645)s as they encourage low-quality questions with a lack of demonstrated effort. This diminishes the purpose of mathematical problem-solving.